# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable when trying to get a list iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator

In a python console:

```
>>> del list # Just to make sure kw: list is not assigned to any variable
>>> my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> my_iter = iter(my_list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>> type(my_list)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
```

What am I missing here? I want an iterable object so that I can access `next()` when looping over it. e.g.:

```
>>> for letter in my_iter:
...     print(next(my_iter))
b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
StopIteration
```

I understand that this will throw an error on the last letter but that's irrelevant.

Comment: You have assigned a list object to the name `iter`. So `iter(...)` will raise that exception, regardless of what you pass in.

Comment: Do you get this same error when you start over again in a new console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bound the name `iter` to a list:

```
>>> my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> iter(my_list)
<list_iterator object at 0x10b1e04e0>
>>> iter = [42]  # rebinding the name iter to a list object
>>> iter(my_list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>> type(iter)
<class 'list'>
>>> callable(iter)
False
```

The exception isn't telling you the list object being passed to the call is the problem. You are not calling the `my_list` object, you are calling `iter`.

Use `del iter` to delete the global name in the current namespace; The `iter()` function is a built-in and it'll be found again once you delete the shadowing global:

```
>>> del iter
>>> iter(my_list)
<list_iterator object at 0x10b1e0358>
>>> type(iter)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> callable(iter)
True
>>> my_iter = iter(my_list)
>>> for letter in my_iter:
...     print(next(my_iter))
...
b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
StopIteration
```

That last traceback *could* be fixed by asking `next()` to return a default instead, e.g. `next(my_iter, 'no more letters')`.

You could also recover the function reference from the [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), so via `builtins.iter`.